# StackTop-Mac app---Now out of beta!

Tags: app, cocoa, mac-os-x, objective-c

**StackTop**

Stacktop is my Mac client for accessing most of the Stack Exchange sites.

Here are some screenshots of 3.0.  Note the colors in the first screenshot change depending on which site you are "visiting":
[image]
[image]

This application will at first be much like a twitter client, then eventually I hope to make it more like an auto-search app where you input keywords then every 10 minutes or so it'll search SO and tell you if there are any questions that haven't been answered that are about whatever your tags are.  Hopefully this will allow SO users to gain more rep and kick Jon Skeet out of #1 (Love you Jon!!!)

This will be released for free.

You can download it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2883198/StackTop3.0.1b.zip)  (Updated link with a version that actually works!!!)

This will be for Mac ONLY

This was written entirely in Objective-C with the help of my Library, [MSOEngine](http://github.com/computermatt/msoengine)

Version 2.9 has been released.

- Bug fixes
- UI enhancements
- Reworked answer window into a drawer.  Makes the overall UX and UI a little cleaner.  I'll post up screenshots of the new UI a little later.

Known Bugs:

- UI Bug in Question Display window, not really a big deal, I'll fix it in 3.0, the official public build.

VERSION 3.0!

StackTop is now out of beta!!!

Contains all the features listed in the 3.0 section, MINUS comments.  I figured comments wasn't a huge deal, so I left them out.  Plus, I couldn't figure out a good way to integrate them

Version 3.0.1 released

-Bug Fixes

**Contact**

You can contact me at matt (at) mattsapps (dot) com

**Public Release (3.0) Features**

I'm very hard at work on StackTop 3.0, so far, here are the new features:

- Tags (finally)
- Auto Search, replacing that placeholder in the preferences :)
- Comments (maybe...)
- Stack Apps Support (Again, finally)
- Reworking some behind the scenes things so EVERY question loads (right now it's at about 99%)

**Notes**

I will NOT be supporting other SE sites UNTIL they are out of beta.  If you've ever used StackTop, then I'm sure you can imagine why.  It really is a pretty big pain to get those colors in the table view (mainly the highlight colors), so I'm not doing it until the site is part of the SE network.  Also, I will not be including the new metas for super user and server fault until there is a new site in the SE network.

Comment: *"a really crappy set of beta testers"* - you might not collect many good beta testers if you keep insulting the ones you've already got... ;-D

Comment: I know I know, it's just that I gave them a version, and none of them ever provided me feedback.

Comment: that's a Beauty!

Comment: Thanks @system  and @josh  Yes, I guess you could consider this a public beta.  The real public beta that I was planning on had sparkle in it so it could autoupdate.  Also, the upcoming version will use the new and improved MSOEngine that is around 100x's more efficient

Comment: What... no support for StackApps?

Comment: @George  no, I MIGHT include it later, but it was giving me problems when I had it in that I have to work out.  The code to do it is still in there so if you want to use fscript and dig around and find it you can unlock it

Comment: I hate to say it but the GUI looks *terrible*.

Comment: which gui?  the one in the screenshots or the one in the actual app?  The one in the screenshots IS terrible, I haven't had time to upload screenshots of the new version.  If it's the one in the actual app, then what's wrong with it?  It's still in beta so any help I can get to make it better is greatly appreciated. Just email me.

Comment: One small enhancement suggestion - when you construct the Gravatar URLs, append `'&d=identicon'` to the end of the query string. This will make the Gravatars match StackOverflow.

Comment: @george thanks for the tip.  I'll add it in the next update

Comment: @Matt: You should submit your app [here](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: The app download link is down—where can we get our hands on this?

Comment: @yuji I've updated the link.  I don't think it works in Lion though.  If I have time later I may try to figure out why it crashes, although there are no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the new link, but you're right: on my Lion machine, the status bar icon pinwheeled for a while without doing anything, and then died.

Comment: @yuji I have updated the link with a version that works on lion