# How the apps-libraries will be judged for the contest?

Tags: discussion, support, contest

Do you know how the apps-library will be judged in term of awesomeness? Is there something more official than [Jeff Atwood's contest post on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/)?

Comment: No. _` ` ` ` ` `_

Comment: Awesome is simple: Just make an [awesome app](http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone).

Comment: @George.  That's a lame app.  I hear this is a truly awesome app! http://stackapps.com/questions/15/stacktop-mac-app-now-out-of-beta

Comment: @Matt: Why is it lame...? At least Windows and Linux users can use it :) I'm just kidding... sort of.

Comment: @george because you don't have an iOS screenshot

Comment: @Matt: Would someone who has one be willing to make one...? Cuz I sure can't.

Comment: @George I got one for you: http://gallery.me.com/davedelong#100084/StackMobile&bgcolor=black

Comment: @Matt your app is lame because you don't have an iOS screenshot either :P  Please try not to be so "zealous" about promoting your app. You don't make yourself look good by putting others down.

Comment: All urz apps are lame. My app has big fonts and twits in the name. Sure fire WIN http://stackapps.com/questions/924/a-stack-of-twits-tweeting-all-over-your-stack

Comment: @dave I didn't think I needed a /sarcasm tag....

Comment: Big font != big benefit.

Comment: @johnwars A Stack of Twits best app evah!